# How to access columns 3 through end column in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am working on a project in MATLAB where my input is a data file (.csv) where the first column is the student ID, the second is the name of the student and from the third column and further are the grades the students have received. A sample could look like this:

```
StudentID,StudentName,Assignment1,Assignment2,Assignment3
s12345,Jane Doe,B,D,A
```

I have already defined the first two columns like this:

```
    studentID = rawData(:,1);
    studentName = rawData(:,2);
```

The code needs to work for any number of assignments, so how do I access the columns number 3 through to the last column? I know that in python it can be written as follows:
`grades = dataFile[:,2::]`

But since I'm pretty new to MATLAB I have no idea of how to achieve the same thing.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @HansHirse It's a 2d-array, so I would rather use `rawData(:,3:end)`

Comment: @Max Meh, you're right. Didn't pay attention to that...

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate - the target question is very similar, and the answer solves your problem, with only the specific index you're interested in being a semantic difference.